# When to use ResourceSavingView?

Tags: react-navigation

Looks like [an interesting option for performance reasons](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/elements/#resourcesavingview). But I cant' find any guide, benchmark or motivation. Does anyone know when we should use `ResourceSavingView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the `react-navigation` source, `ResourceSavingView` is only used in a component called [MaybeScreen](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/e13b4d9341362512ba4bf921a17552f3be8735c1/packages/bottom-tabs/src/views/ScreenFallback.tsx#L36). The purpose of this component is to use `react-native-screens` if it is available or fallback to a ResourceSavingView if it is not available, as you can see [here](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/e13b4d9341362512ba4bf921a17552f3be8735c1/packages/bottom-tabs/src/views/ScreenFallback.tsx#L46):

```js
export function MaybeScreen({ visible, children, ...rest }: Props) {
  if (Screens?.screensEnabled?.()) {
    return (
      <Screens.Screen activityState={visible ? 2 : 0} {...rest}>
        {children}
      </Screens.Screen>
    );
  }

  return (
    <ResourceSavingView visible={visible} {...rest}>
      {children}
    </ResourceSavingView>
  );
}
```

In other words, if you are using `react-native-screens`, `ResourceSavingView` will never be used internally by `react-navigation`.

The actual [`ResourceSavingView` component](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/b91c9b05ff96727f5fa6ef0bec51b5d7eac06600/packages/elements/src/ResourceSavingView.tsx#L44) is fairly simple:

```js
<View
  style={[styles.container, style]}
  // box-none doesn't seem to work properly on Android
  pointerEvents={visible ? 'auto' : 'none'}
>
  <View
    collapsable={false}
    removeClippedSubviews={
      // On iOS, set removeClippedSubviews to true only when not focused
      // This is an workaround for a bug where the clipped view never re-appears
      Platform.OS === 'ios' ? !visible : true
    }
    pointerEvents={visible ? 'auto' : 'none'}
    style={visible ? styles.attached : styles.detached}
  >
    {children}
  </View>
</View>
```

As you can see, it's basically just enabling some performance features when the component is `visible`.

The main purposes seem to be disabling [pointerEvents](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view#pointerevents) and hilariously moving the contents of the view `FAR_FAR_AWAY`:

```js
const FAR_FAR_AWAY = 30000; // this should be big enough to move the whole view out of its container

// ...

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  // ...
  detached: {
    flex: 1,
    top: FAR_FAR_AWAY,
  },
});
```

So, to answer your question, as far as I can tell it is intended to be used to improve performance when you need a `View` to be rendered but not always visible. This is something `react-navigation` needs because things like transition animations require that `Screen`s remain mounted even when they aren't visible.

Of course, depending on your situation, you can always use `pointerEvents` and weird style hacks directly instead.

Personally, I would avoid using `ResourceSavingView`. I wouldn't be surprised if `ResourceSavingView` is eventually deprecated, since it is very clearly used as a fallback. (The file it's used in is actually called [ScreenFallback.tsx](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/e13b4d9341362512ba4bf921a17552f3be8735c1/packages/bottom-tabs/src/views/ScreenFallback.tsx).)